# Insert multiple rows to My SQL table using SP

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have to insert multiple records to table using SP in My Sql.
Table: Options

```
OID QID Text
1   1   “ABC”
2   1   “DEF”
3   1   “PQR”
```

column description

```
OID – Auto incremented.
QID – Values passed from outside
Text – Values passed from outside
```

I can write the Insert query like below but want to write SP.

```
Insert Into Options (QID,Text) Values( 1, “ABC”),(1,”DEF”),(1,”PQR”)
```

How to achieve this using SP in MySql?

Comment: What do you mean by `SP`?  Stored procedure?  What do you want your stored procedure to do?  Just insert the data that is provided to it as parameters?  If so, will it always insert (up to) three records, or are there no limits on the number that might be inserted in a single call (one assumes that you cannot call the sproc once for each record that is to be inserted)?

Comment: Yes..Stored procedure For inserting the data. And parameters can vary in the example it is 3 but it can be one or more than one

Comment: This isn't a task that is well suited to a sproc.  Why are you trying to use one?

Comment: Because In my C# code I have to built query depending on number of rows. I have to use concatenation and lot of string related operation like remove last comma etc.

Comment: So then build a query in C# depending on the number of rows?

Comment: Can't we pass parameter as string array to Stored procedure and execute in one go

Comment: No. MySQL does not have an array datatype.